# Modular multiplicative inverse problem.

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I am trying to calculate the multiplicative inverse of big integers of 256 bits and I am not able to find a good calculator to resolve it.

I have found some online calculators but the result is not correct.

Can someone please help? thanks.

Comment: Do you know about the extended Euclidean algorithm?

Comment: Did you try with python?

Comment: The calculator GP/PARI can do it very easily. Example `Mod(110528812453801822904317758417383912041757712635384174764936784734826169201757, 123897535483928329103220953959296061402998883592235403522219614888467048714837)^(-1)`.

Comment: I know about the Euclidean algorithm but using it with 256 bits numbers is really hard to do it without a calculator.

Comment: Do you have any recommendation for a python script N74?

Comment: Can you please share the link for the GP/PARI calculator Nielsen? thanks

Comment: In python just use `pow(v, N-2, N)` for prime $N$